# fastest way for 2D Array element by element comparision

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array 
`int[,] b = { { 1, 0, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };`

I want to check condition in array element by element in such a way that if previous value of array index is different from current value of array then one of my counters get incremented.Return type of whole array is also 1D array.
Here row represents my channel and column represent number of sample value.

I can do it by 2 loops and compare element by element as i had already done same in delphi7 but now i am working on C#. So is there any smart and fastest way to do the same please tell.

The output of above array is 
`int [] output = {2}` as `1->0` so increment again `0->1` then again increment then one so same state so no increment so total value is `2`.

Same for all othere elements so output will be `[2,2,1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with Linq I guess.

```
int[,] b = { { 1, 0, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, b.GetLength(0))
        .Select(row => Enumerable.Range(0, b.GetLength(1)-1).Count(col => b[row, col + 1] != b[row, col])).ToArray();
```

Where:

`b.GetLength(0)` - Get number of rows in array

`b.GetLength(1)` - Get number of columns in array

`Count(y => b[row, col + 1] != b[row, col]))` - Count only different items

Comment: Can you explain what value x  and y hold because as per linq x  should have row length of array b and y should have column length of array. but according to code it seems different.

Comment: I have edited code above. 'x' is processing row number and 'y' is processing column number. I have changed it to row and col. This is because row comes from `Enumerable.Range(0, b.GetLength(0))` that is range of rows 0 to number of rows in array. Similar is for columns. Except range is 1 item less as I compare item with next one.